# Tridion 2009 SP1 TcmUploadAssembly not able to overwrite existing TBBs

Tags: tridion, tridion2009

I am using the TcmUploadAssembly utility in a post-build event but am receiving the following error from the tool.

> Error 1 Name must be unique for items of type: Template Building Block
>   within this Folder and its BluePrint context. Source or sources  of
>   conflict:
>   tcm:5-200-2048.   C:\Projects\Project1\src\Tridion\TBBs\EXEC  Compound
>   Templates

The TcmId given refers to the Assembly stored in Tridion which I would expect because that is what I am overwriting. In the past this "just worked". Am I missing something?

Notes:

1. My user is an admin
2. The Tridion instance is on my network so I am using credentials in context.
3. I have specified all settings via the command line (no config.xml is used)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say check your Blueprint context (i.e. the Publication you are in). This error means you are trying to create the TBB, yet there is already an item with the same name **probably somewhere down in the Blueprint child Publications**.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have just realised I was trying to upload higher in the Blueprint than I intended.

Answer (score 3):

Classic writing out the problem and the problem solves itself...

I discovered the folder is set in the AssemblyInfo as well and I had the folder set incorrectly on the command line (Blueprinting issue).

I ran into a second problem however, if I set `uploadpdb:true` on the command line I receive this error

```
Error   1   Could not write file: c:\Temp
```

Setting `uploadpdb:false` resolves the issue.

Comment: Indeed c:\temp is the location where the PDB is written to. IIRC, it is the user that runs the Tridion CME website that has to have write permissions for the folder. If not, a Process Monitor looking at the file system will tell you who is trying to write to it. You will need this PDB if you want to have some nice source names and lines in the stack traces ;)